# SSMS Update Causes Connection Failure and Exception Error

Tags: .net, connection, ssms

After updating SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I've encountered an issue where the Object Explorer window displays the following error message:

```
An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame. This information is also logged in "C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppEnv\15.0\ActivityLog.xml".
Details:
System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

Attempted Solutions:

Reverting to a previous version of SSMS and then updating again.
Repairing the Microsoft SQL Server installation.
Updating Visual Studio.
Expected Outcome:
I expected that one of these steps would resolve the issue, allowing me to use SSMS as usual without encountering the error.

Question:
How can I resolve this issue to restore normal functionality to SSMS?

Comment: How is .Net related here? Have you installed some kind of extension you wrote in .Net in SSMS?

Comment: Also, what version of SSMS are you using? Have you tried the latest release (version 20).

Comment: I'm using the latest version.

Comment: Then how did you update it? There's no updates out for SSMS 20 yet; the GA release only came out 5 days ago.